# Connection property has not been initialized when filling a DataSet

Tags: asp.net, connection-string, server-error

So here is my issue:

Currently I am trying to make a report that will show 1st and 2nd shifts, by multiple days...

So if they select the range 6/02 - 6/04, I am running a query 3 times... once for 6/02, 6/03, and 6/04... Also they can select shift, so it would be those dates, but 4:30AM-4:30PM for 1st shift....

Currently I have a error, when trying to put my queries/calls inside the for loop... I calculate the difference of the two dates and set them up fine, its just my connection string gives me the error:

[image]

If the image is not easy to see here is a text description of the error:

> Server Error in '/mfgx_test' Application.
>
> Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Fill:
>   SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 623:        Dim dsTop1 As New DataSet Line 624:        Dim daTop1
>   As New SqlDataAdapter(strSql, myCn1) Line 625:
>   daTop1.Fill(dsTop1) Line 626: Line 627:        myCn1.Close()
>
> Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mfgx_test\defectsbyround.aspx.vb
>   Line: 625

Which leads me to beleive that something is wrong with my connection string being outside of my for loop... My code is as follows (Although a bit cleaned up so it is easier to read):

```
    Dim myCn1 As New SqlConnection
    myCn1.ConnectionString = "server=Blah;database=Blah;user id=Blah;password=Blah"
    myCn1.Open()

    For i = 0 To Session("DaysDiff")
        strSql = "Blah.Blah"
        Dim dsTop1 As New DataSet
        Dim daTop1 As New SqlDataAdapter(strSql, myCn1)
        daTop1.Fill(dsTop1)

        myCn1.Close()
        myCn1 = Nothing

        If dsTop1.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
           spitout2(dsTop1)
        End If

           txtStartdate.Text = DateAdd("d",1,txtStartdate.Text)
           txtEnddate.Text = DateAdd("d",1,txtEnddate.Text)
   Next
```

Comment: Well you close the connection *inside* the loop so the next time round .... if you want to reuse it then close when the loop is done.

Comment: That's not classic ASP, it's Asp.Net written in VB.Net

Comment: Its on my .aspx.vb file, Figured it was a little bit of both... but when I choose vb.net the colors on my code part disappeared so I left it off, but thank you for clarifing

Comment: And @AlexK. I dont know how I missed that, but thank you so much :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are closing the connection inside your loop and so for next iteration there is no open connection present and hence the exception (see pointed below)

```
   myCn1.Close()
    myCn1 = Nothing
```

You should declare the `Dataset` and `tableadapter` as well out side the loop context. Your code should somewhat look like below

```
Dim myCn1 As New SqlConnection
myCn1.ConnectionString = "server=Blah;database=Blah;user id=Blah;  password=Blah"
myCn1.Open()
Dim dsTop1 As New DataSet
Dim daTop1

For i = 0 To Session("DaysDiff")
    strSql = "Blah.Blah"
    daTop1 As New SqlDataAdapter(strSql, myCn1)
    daTop1.Fill(dsTop1)

 .......
Next

     myCn1.Close()
    myCn1 = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to reuse the connection inside the loop, release the connection automatically with a `Using` statement outside the `for` loop

```
Using myCn1 As New SqlConnection("server=Blah;database=Blah;user id=Blah;password=Blah")
    myCn1.Open()

    For i = 0 To Session("DaysDiff")
        strSql = "Blah.Blah"
        Dim dsTop1 As New DataSet
        Dim daTop1 As New SqlDataAdapter(strSql, myCn1)
        daTop1.Fill(dsTop1)

        If dsTop1.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
           spitout2(dsTop1)
        End If

           txtStartdate.Text = DateAdd("d",1,txtStartdate.Text)
           txtEnddate.Text = DateAdd("d",1,txtEnddate.Text)
    Next

End Using
```

When `End Using` is reached, `SqlConnection.Dispose()` will be called, releasing connection resources.